# Where to ask question about business valuation

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I don't know where I should ask a question I have about including the value of a premium domain into the value of a business.

- the business is a startup
- the domain name is a 4 letter .com that is the name of the brand
- the company is online software company in the restaurant and eatery space
- the company is located in the U.K. but could be sold internationally

For example, if the domain cost $30,000 how much would that add, if anything, to the value of the business if the business was to ever be sold? Would that be on the Finance Stack Exchange?

Comment: I think that this depends to a degree *how* will that business be sold, what country and legislation you are on, what sort of entity/company that is (private, startup, can one buy shares of it, etc.). Perhaps if you scope it down a bit the site where it belongs would be more evident...

Comment: Thanks @DarkCygnus, have added some clarification